# Unable to create media player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

```
 package com.example.instrumentapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private Button E;
        private MediaPlayer play;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            E=(Button)findViewById(R.id.E);
            E.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    play=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.e);
                    play.start();
                    play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
                    {


                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            play.release();
                        }

                });
            }
            });




        }
    }
```

I am trying to play an e note.

There is an e.wav file in raw folder.

There is a button id/E in the xml folder.

This is the only class in the project.

When i run the app and click the button it says unexpectedly closed.

What is wrong ?

Here is LOGCAT ;

```
05-13 23:04:29.374: E/MediaPlayer(469): Unable to to create media player
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469): create failed:
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:645)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at com.example.instrumentapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/MediaPlayer(469):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 23:04:29.384: D/AndroidRuntime(469): Shutting down VM
05-13 23:04:29.384: W/dalvikvm(469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.example.instrumentapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-13 23:04:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is this MediaPlayer you speak of?  I don't know if it's an object or if it's an application or what it could possibly be...

Comment: Ok it doesn't matter. The only thing i need is to use raw folder as a source folder to call wav files but it says raw cannot be resolved.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help you with this.  We don't even know what language you're talking about.

Comment: Ok i know that there is not enough detail. This is eclipse adt. I created raw folder inside res.It is not visible.

Comment: For your sake, you would want to add more detail to your question.  Things like which language you're using, which version of the language you're using, and which framework you're using to pay the media is **helpful**.

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously that the MediaPlayer object is not created successfully. Here is the implementation of the API MediaPlayer.create():

```
  public static MediaPlayer create(Context context, int resid) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
        if (afd == null) return null;

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        mp.prepare();
        return mp;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
       // fall through
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    }
    return null;
}
```

Apparently, `mp.setDataSource` throws an IOException and thus returns a null MediaPlayer object. Please double check your e.wav in the raw directory:

- Is it in the right directory?
- Or is it a valid wav file?

Comment: What i want to do is that playing a short wav sound. By using 7 different short notes i will create a simple piano app. This should have been an easy task but i couldnt have done it. Appearently soundpool method is better for short files. But the samples i found didnt work. Please do you have any example for this? if i can play just one sound by clicking on a button i think i can manage to play 7 of them too. That is very important , if you can show me a way i would be very grateful